# hasAttribute, if condition and click event

Tags: javascript, attributes, click, listener

I am pretty new to programming, so apologies if this seems like an easy question I should know the answer to.

I basically want to listen to the click of user on a specific div (article-title) and check if the class has an attribute (value = 1).
-I actually set the values of the div elsewhere in the code to 0, to see if this works, I want it to log "nope" in the console to be sure that the code saw the if statement about the value's value.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
document.getElementsByClassName('article-title')[I]
.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   if(articleSource.hasAttribute("value"),("1");
   console.log("nope");

});
```

Comment: You say "check if the class has an attribute" I'm not sure what that means. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include an example of the HTML you're trying to target? Also, where is `articleSource` defined?

Answer (score 1):

There is some syntax errors

1) index [I] doesn't mean anything. As you have maybe noticed, `.getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection (= an array, a list) of elements. So you have to take the index [0] if you're sure there is only one element `article-title`. But actually I advise you to use `.querySelector('.article-title')`, which will return 1 element.

2) In the `If` statement you have to compare with `===` (or at least `==`)
Secondly, hasAttribute doesn't return the value, but the presence. So you have to 
`if(articleSource.getAttribute('value') === '1')` but...

3) What is `articleSource` ? Could you show us how you initialized it ? Are you sure this is a HTMLElement ?

Comment: Thanks! I actually thought I was answering to you directly, but the answer explaining my next steps appeared above

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement at the code at the question has a syntax error at

```
if(articleSource.hasAttribute("value"),("1");
```

where the comma operator is not a comparison operator, parenthesis around `"1"` are not necessary, and closing parenthesis around `if` statement is missing, followed by a semicolon `;`.

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` to get all elements where a specific `class` is set, use `.forEach()` to iterate elements, check the element attribute using `.getAttribute()` which returns a string, compare values using strict equality operator.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.article-title')
.forEach(function (articleSource, index) {
  articleSource.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (articleSource.getAttribute("value") === "1") {
      console.log("nope");
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer using a `for loop` with your `getElementsByClassName` since it returns a `HTMLCollection`; You won't be able to use a `forEach` on a HTMLCollection.

Once we `iterated` over each element, we add an event listener that basically obtains the elements instance and retrieve the attribute `value` by using `getAttribute`.

Once we have the value we can just wrap it in an `if` block (or ternary) and just log if the value equals 1 or not.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('article-title');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
     if (this.getAttribute('value') === "1") {
        return console.log('yes');
     }
     return console.log('no');
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.article-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-title">1 = no</div>
<div class="article-title">2 = no</div>
<div class="article-title" value="1">3 = yes</div>
```

GetElementsByClassName: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

HTMLCollection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your answers. 
So a few things so you guys see clearer.

Basically this is an NewsAPI project, so the `articleSource` is introduced by the api request, and I assign a class to it

`articleSource.classList.add("article-source");`

It seems to work now having corrected the if statement syntax error. 
Regarding the value of the attribute, I set it initially after the APIRequest (I get 6 article titles per request). I set it before with

`articleSource.setAttribute('value',"0");`

I did that to check that the if statement worked, setting the initial value to 0 and the if statement to one would not write anything in the console, but if I changed the initial value to 1, I would see the console log.

Basically, I wanted to figure this out for the next step of my project, which will be to assign a different value to each of the 6 articles when the request is made, and then read those values on click, storing them into an array; so that I have an array of only the ones that were clicked and their value.